# El Capitan: every app crashes when browsing or saving file

Tags: crash, macos, file

Yesterday I updated my Mac to El Capitan. I have a serious issue, as every app is crashing, when I am trying to browse files.

Examples:

- Photoshop crashed when I try to save a file, or place a file (crashes when I try to browse)
- (tried on chrome and safari) - when trying to upload files on Facebook conversation, the app crashes as I try to browse/pick a file.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here are my two cents:

I experienced the exact same issue you describe.
What resolved it for me was to delete the Finder's preferences plist file

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Then log out/in, or reboot, and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that Finder is corrupted in some way.

First back up your files. (Manually copy to External HD or use Time Machine to do it for you)

Now that you've backed up:
Boot to recovery (Command + R, while powering on) and then reinstall OSX over your current install. This should repair/replace any damaged files that could be causing Finder to misbehave.