# Apps randomly crash when using keyboard shortcuts in popups

Tags: keyboard, crash, macos

For some weird reason, hitting Enter, Escape, or some other action keys crash the save dialog, open dialog, Command+F, and many others. This makes the entire app crash, and revert to an autosave which is likely very outdated (if at all).

This is after upgrading from El Capitan.

I can confirm clicking the Open, Save, Cancel etc buttons with the mouse work fine, but when I use the keyboard, the entire app crashes.

How do I fix this?

Edit: The following list will be updated with all solutions I have tried, and have failed:

- [El Capitan: every app crashes when browsing or saving file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210879/el-capitan-every-app-crashes-when-browsing-or-saving-file?rq=1)

Edit 2: I have confirmed this issue also applies to authentication dialogs and the like.

Edit 3: Somehow it got fixed. I don't know how or what caused it, but it just was. If anybody can educate me on this and tell me how this could have happened, please do.

Edit 4: The issue popped up again. I have no idea why.

Comment: Which apps are you having trouble with? How old is your Mac?

Comment: Every single app. This includes Command+Down, Command+Up, and other navigation shortcuts. Things like Command+Shift+G work fine, but when you hit Esc or Enter, finder hits an exception. This also is true for the find dialog in apps like Google Chrome.

Comment: My mac is little more than 6 months old, purchased on February 21, 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a faulty keyboard layout produced by Ukelele seems to be the culprit. Switching to the default keyboard layout fixed it for me. If someone can shed some light on how this works I would appreciate it.